# SheetCalculate - How does this sub routine run?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this module here that has is Workbook subroutine. I can't for the life of me understand how the GenerateLimitSummary is ever able to run? Can someone please articulate the process flow here?

```
Private LimitBool As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    If LimitBool Then Exit Sub

    ' use conditional formatting to highlight limit breaches
    ApplyConditionalFormatting

    ' regenerate the summary limits sheet
    LimitBool = True
    GenerateLimitSummary
    LimitBool = False

End Sub
```

Comment: When the code first runs, `LimitBool` is `False` so the code goes to the next line and processes `ApplyConditionalFormatting`. Once that finishes, it moves to the next line and you set the boolean to `True` and after that `GenerateLimitSummary` runs. The boolean is set to `False` again so that the `Workbook_SheetCalculate` doesn't go into a loop. You might want to switch off events rather than using the boolean variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author uses LimitBool to prevent a infinite loop/a stack overflow:

- Initially, `LimitBool` is `False`, therefore the remainder of `Workbook_SheetCalculate`is executed
- Now, `LimitBool` is set to `True` (after it was confirmed it's not `True`)
- `GenerateLimitSummary` is executed. If this routine now for some reasons forces the workbook to recalculate, `Workbook_SheetCalculate` will be triggered again. However, as `LimitBool` is now `True`*, the second call to this procedure is now Exited after the first check. If it would not have this check, it would again call `GenerateLimitSummary`, which would then trigger the recalc, etc...
- After the `GenerateLimitSummary`ran, `LimitBool` is set back to `False`, therefore, it can ran again

(*) - it has a Module-wide scope, i.e. it keeps it value across the different calls, while a procedure-wide scope (=Dimmed in the sub) would create a new variable for each call